# Change prefix Figure 1 to Fig. S1. in latex

Tags: latex, overleaf

I want to ask, How can I change prefix in the caption from Figure 1 into Fig. S1. in latex?. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

This might help:

```
\setcounter{figure}{0}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig.}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{S\arabic{figure}}
```

The first line resets the count and is not necessary if you want to do it for the whole document. But if you want to do it for a specific section (maybe supplementary section is at the end of your document) then put these three lines at the start of that section and the first line would reset figure counter.

Answer (score 1):

You have to redefine the `\figurename`. You can find usefull information [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17489/change-caption-name-of-figures).